# Using variable holding selectors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".focus-button").addClass('active');
$(".focus-button[data-expand='true']").addClass('active');
```

If I store the class selector in a variable like:

```
var btn = $(".focus-button");
```

The variable can be used in the code as

```
btn.addClass('active'); // This is correct
btn[data-expand='true'].addClass('active'); // This is wrong
```

May I know what is the right way to use variable with attributes.

Comment: `filter` http://api.jquery.com/filter/   `btn.filter("[data-expand='true']")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter) to add additional selectors in the way you want.

> Reduce the set of matched elements to those that match the selector or pass the function's test.

Example:

```
var btn = $(".focus-button");
btn.addClass("active");
btn.filter("[data-expand='true']").removeClass("active")
```

Where

```
var btn = $(".focus-button");
btn.filter("[data-expand='true']")
```

is the same as

```
$(".focus-button[data-expand='true']")
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. have a Great day.

Answer (score 2):

**Situation:**

In your actual code, if you write:

```
var btn = $(".focus-button");
```

You will get a collection of all elements with class `focus-button`, so when you write, `btn.addClass('active');` it's correct and it will add the class `active` to all the elements in this collection.

**Problem:**

While when you write:

```
btn[data-expand='true'].addClass('active');
```

It's wrong because JavaScript will interpret it as you are accessing a property in your `btn` object, because `[]` are only used to access a specific `property` in an `object` or a specific element by `index` in an `array`.

And `btn[data-expand='true']` is only a **CSS** selector.

**Solution:**

You can use [jQuery **.filter()**](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) as suggested in comments, like this:

```
btn.filter("[data-expand='true']").addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have a Great day

Answer (score 1):

try this snippet:

```js
//$(".focus-button").addClass('active');
//$(".focus-button[data-expand='true']").addClass('active');


var btn = $(".focus-button");
//btn.addClass('active'); 

btn.filter("[data-expand='true']").addClass('active');
```

```css
.active{
background: #000;
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="focus-button">F</div>
<div class="focus-button" data-expand="true">E</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have a Great day

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
btn.filter("data-expand='true'").addClass('active');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Have a Great day